# In a remote thread, how do I call functions whose parameters contain pointers?

Tags: delphi, code-injection, dll-injection

I want to call `SHFileOperation` using code injection. My code works fine while calling simple
functions like `MessageBox` from `user32.dll`, but won't while calling `ShFileOperation` from `shell32.dll`.

I'll post the part of the code that I think has the problem. I know the problem is in the struct implementation.

Here is the image of RemoteInfo value:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/219d79fc30.jpg

```
//Structure
type
  LPSHFILEOPSTRUCT = ^SHFILEOPSTRUCT;
  SHFILEOPSTRUCT = packed record
    Wnd: HWND;
    wFunc: UINT;
    pFrom: PAnsiChar;
    pTo: PAnsiChar;
    fFlags: FILEOP_FLAGS;
    fAnyOperationsAborted: BOOL;
    hNameMappings: Pointer;
    lpszProgressTitle: PAnsiChar;
  end;

//Remote Info
type
  TRemoteInfo = record
    LoadLibrary: function(lpLibFileName: PChar): HMODULE; stdcall;
    GetProcAddress: function(hModule: HMODULE;
      lpProcName: LPCSTR): FARPROC; stdcall;
    shf: SHFILEOPSTRUCT; ;
    Kernel32: array[0..20] of Char;
    shell32: array[0..20] of Char;
    SHFileOperationA: array[0..20] of Char;
    Fromlpbuff: array[0..20] of char; //Source path
    Tolpbuff: array[0..20] of Char;   //Des Path
  end;

//Initialize                      
                      ....
ZeroMemory(@RemoteInfo, SizeOf(RemoteInfo));
  RemoteInfo.shf.Wnd := 0;
  RemoteInfo.shf.wFunc := FO_COPY;
  RemoteInfo.shf.pFrom := @remoteInfo.Fromlpbuff;
  RemoteInfo.shf.pto := @remoteInfo.tolpbuff;
  lstrcpy(RemoteInfo.shf.pFrom, 'e:\1.jpg' + #0#0);
  lstrcpy(RemoteInfo.shf.pto, 'f:\1.jpg' + #0#0);
  RemoteInfo.shf.fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO;
  RemoteInfo.shf.fAnyOperationsAborted := false;
                      ....
```

Comment: Or... you could be polite and tell us you are doing this for legit reasons. Then, with a little q&a back and forth to fill in the blatant gaps in the info you provided we could work out a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think you can do something useful instead of be a listener

Comment: -1, smells like malware and OP is not very helpful in comments.

Comment: Sam, are you covering your tracks up? Your recent edits do not make much sense!

Comment: @RvD: "smells like malware" helps answer writers by warning them they might be helping a scammer; it helps questioners by indicating they need a less-sinister problem statement/explanation.

Comment: @joe snyder - You're not seeing what 'RvD' commented on, it was removed. And I (and maybe others) had flagged the one the OP had commented on RvD's one, that one also was removed.

Comment: @Sertac: i was responding to his response to my original comment, all of which are still visible.

Comment: @joe - I know RvD can talk for himself, I'm just responding again since it seems that I've not been able to make myself clear. I'll try again; RvD did **not** respond to your comment, his comment is a reaction to the OP's response to your first comment which involved an insult to you.

Comment: Sertac is right, I was just agreeing with you, joe. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem in this code is that you're storing pointers to the string parameters in your record. Those pointers are addresses in your *main* process; they are not valid in the target process. You should store those values in fixed-size arrays in your record, just like you're already doing with the module and function names. Then initialize the pointer fields inside the remote function.

But you're really making it more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need to use `GetProcAddress` in the remote function at all. Put you *entire function* in a DLL. There you can call whatever functions you want, and the Delphi linker and the OS loader will ensure that they're all available to call at run time. You also don't need to allocate all your variables with `VirtualAllocEx`; you can use ordinary local variables in your DLL function.

You'll use `CreateRemoteThread` three times over the course of your program. The first time is to inject a call to `LoadLibrary` to get your DLL into the target process's address space. The second time is to invoke your injected function, and the third time is to call `FreeLibrary` after you're finished. The tricky part is finding the address of your injected function in the target process. [Alexey Kurakin's article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90271/Remote-threads-basics-Part-2.aspx) demonstrates how to do that by finding the *relative* address of the function in your own process, and the applying that offset to the remote process to determine the argument to pass to your second call to `CreateRemoteThread`.

Finally, there's no need to declare the support records for `ShFileOperation` yourself. Delphi already declares them for you in the *ShellAPI* unit. There you'll also find the named constants for the various flags you need, like `fo_Copy` instead of `$0002`.

Comment: thx MR kennedy but i want to do this by declare the struct by my self i'm making some changes  i'll post it

Comment: If you change the definition of the struct, then it's no longer compatible with what ShFileOperation expects to receive. You don't get to negotiate with the API. When the API says a field is a pointer, you need to provide a pointer, not an array. The API function is going to take that value and treat it like a pointer by dereferencing it to read the characters it points to. Or are you also rewriting ShFileOperation?

Comment: I know the definition should be same as the api,but when i use pointer instead of array, the path won't be in correct format, i don't know how to make the result as the image while using pointer instead of array?!!!

Comment: I see. You're concerned because when you have an ordinary PChar field, the *debugger* doesn't display the null characters at the end of the strings. That's because the *debugger* doesn't know that the character pointer you're inspecting is treated specially. The debugger just treats it the same as it treats all other character-pointer types: It displays the characters until it reaches a null character. Just because it doesn't show you the null characters at the end doesn't mean they aren't there. Please refer to any of the hundreds of examples available demonstrating ShFileOperation in Delphi.

Comment: the above code and the image is now edited again

Comment: I don't know what should i do with this,the api doesn't accept the paths

Comment: in the new image the format of "pto" and "pfrom" is not correct,it should be like "fromlpbuff" and "tolpbuff"

Comment: As I *just* told you, that's the way the debugger *displays* character pointers, including `pFrom` and `pTo`. The debugger does not display the null characters at the ends of those strings, but you should not interpret *that* as evidence that the null characters aren't there. The debugger simply doesn't show them to you. But actually, you're only guaranteed that *one* is there. The `lstrcpy` function stops after the first null character. The rest are null because you used `ZeroMemory` earlier. To copy the nulls at the end of a string, use `StrPLCopy` instead.

Comment: The code *can* be used in a remote process. Put all your code in a DLL. Load the DLL in the remote process. Call your DLL function in the remote process. The link I gave shows how to do that. Put your string argument in the array with StrPLCopy. Copy the array into the remote process's address space. In the DLL, simply assign the array to the pointer parameter: `shf.pFrom := PRemoteInfo(Param).Fromlpbuff;`